# Удаление класса родителя по клику на внутренний элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему по клику на блок `.close` не убирается класс у родителя?

```js
$('.modal').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hi');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.modal').removeClass('hi');
});
```

```css
.hi {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">123</div>
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $(document).on("click", '.close', function() { /*code*/ });

Comment: @Regent https://jsfiddle.net/koba140g/

Comment: @soledar10 а, да, не продумал вариант до конца. Хоть и достаточно костыльно, но таки работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Клик по `.close` приводит к вызову обработчика как для `.close`, так и для `.model`. Соответственно, класс удаляется и следом снова добавляется.
Как вариант, можно запрещать "всплывание" события:

```js
$('.modal').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hi');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.modal').removeClass('hi');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.hi {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">123</div>
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.modal').click(function(event) { 
    $(event.target).hasClass('close') ? $(this).removeClass('hi') : $(this).addClass('hi');
});
```

```css
.hi {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">123</div>
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Скобки вокруг `$(event.target).hasClass('close')` лишние, а в целом вариант мне нравится: как-никак, всего один обработчик `click` вместо двух.

Comment: @Regent а спасибо, учёл)

Answer (score 1):

Класс у родителя удаляется, и после этого клик всплывает к нему, где класс добавляется заново. По клику на `.close` нужно отключать дальнейшее всплытие события.

```js
$('.modal').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hi');
});

$('.close').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.modal').removeClass('hi');
});
```

```css
.hi {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">123</div>
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, например, все работает:

```js
$('.modal').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hi');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.modal').removeClass('hi');
});
```

```css
.hi {
  color: green;
}
.modal {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
.close {
  width:40px;
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  position:relative;
  top:-100px;
  left:60px
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">123</div>
</div>
<div class="close">X</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: потому что, открывается и закрывается по клику на разные кнопки

Comment: То есть структура html принципиальна? Вынос класса "close" за пределы класса "modal" решает проблему. Если нужно чтобы они отображались как родительский и дочерний - можно через css натянуть например крестик на угол "модального окна"

Comment: @SoVerk а зачем менять HTML и заморачиваться за CSS, если проблема решается минимальными изменениями в JS?